# If I wanted to drive due west around the earth would I need to turn my steering wheel?

Tags: projective-geometry, spherical-geometry

Assume I found a land route around the earth that followed a single line of latitude and was perfectly smooth.

I want to drive my car due west around the earth and return to the same point that I started at. Would I need to turn my steering wheel (assume the distance between my car's axles is negligible)?

Googling this has given me results about "Rhumb Lines", and I know that the Mercator projection has something to do with the answer, but I am battling to understand how these concepts fit together.

Comment: If you start on the equator, you don't have to turn the steering wheel. If you start 100 m north of the South Pole (where there is indeed a land route), you would clearly have to turn your steering wheel to the left. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to turn a little if your line of latitude is not the equator. If you go always in front of your, you'll do a great circle :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle